# Install MultiUpload Extension in MediaWiki

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wiki

I am trying to install ["MultiUpload"](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMultiUpload) mediawiki extension.

I followed the installation instructions and added below code to my mediawiki "LocalSetting.php" file
`require_once("/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/MultiUpload/MultiUpload.php");`

but when I tried to verify the installation by go to the webpage `http://myserverIP/wiki/index.php/Special:Version`

It gave me "http error 500". However I have successfully installed "FCKeditor" extension by using the below command and it went on very well:

```
sudo apt-get install mediawiki-extensions
sudo mwenext ParserFunctions.php
```

My Apache error log shows:

```
[Tue Mar 20 13:40:18 2012] [error] [client 172.29.35.61] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/MultiUpload/MultiUpload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /etc/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php on line 142
[Tue Mar 20 13:40:18 2012] [error] [client 172.29.35.61] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/MultiUpload/MultiUpload.php' (include_path='/var/lib/mediawiki:/var/lib/mediawiki/includes:/var/lib/mediawiki/languages:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /etc/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php on line 142
[Tue Mar 20 13:40:19 2012] [error] [client 172.29.35.61] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/MultiUpload/MultiUpload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /etc/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php on line 142
[Tue Mar 20 13:40:19 2012] [error] [client 172.29.35.61] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/MultiUpload/MultiUpload.php' (include_path='/var/lib/mediawiki:/var/lib/mediawiki/includes:/var/lib/mediawiki/languages:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /etc/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php on line 142
```

My "MultiUpload" directory shows:

```
total 112
drwxrwxr-x 2 2010  500  4096 2009-06-10 15:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 2012-03-20 13:38 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 2010  500   788 2009-06-10 15:57 multiupload.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 2010  500  1100 2009-06-10 15:57 README
-rw-rw-r-- 1 2010  500  2942 2009-06-10 15:57 SpecialMultipleUpload.alias.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 2010  500 13314 2009-06-10 15:57 SpecialMultipleUpload.body.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 2010  500 70689 2009-06-10 15:57 SpecialMultipleUpload.i18n.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 2010  500  3188 2009-06-10 15:57 SpecialMultipleUpload.php
```

May I know how to troubleshoot this error and get this extension working on my mediawiki?

I am using Ubuntu11.04, MediaWiki 1.15.5-3.

Comment: Have you checked the apache error log?  When you created the `extensions/MultiUpload` directory, were permissions such that your apache user can read from it?

Comment: I have tried to use "www-data" as my "MultiUpload" folder owner recursively and changed read/write/access to the file "MultiUpload.php" (make it 777) but still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache error 500 is "Internal Server Error", so one needs to examine the apache error logs for the crucial details.  In your case, the error logs seem to indicate that the file you are requiring, `/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/MultiUpload/MultiUpload.php`, does not exist.

According to your listing of the `MultiUpload` directory, the file `MultiUpload.php` is not in it.  Is `MultiUpload.php` in the extensions directory?  If so, then what you want in your `LocalSettings.php` is:

```
require_once("/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/MultiUpload.php");
```

[edit] ... or more likely you *really* want to load the `SpecialMultipleUpload.php` file, which actually *is* in your MultiUpload directory, in which case you want to use this:

```
require_once("/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/MultiUpload/SpecialMultipleUpload.php");
```

In any case, you can only require files that actually exist.

Comment: After some digging I found the "MultiUpload.php" is not in the extension folder, the name should be "SpecialMultipleUpload.php". I  changed the file name and it worked.